# React Route Splitting Code cannot load chunk

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i try to forwards React Route [Huge App Example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps). But, after webpack splitting code, always load chunk with 404.

Here is my Router.

```
<Router history={appHistory} >
  <Route path='/' component={RootContainer}>
    <IndexRoute component={MainContainer}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path='/demo1' getComponent={(location, cb) => {
      require.ensure([], require => {
        cb(null, require('../../components/container/DemoContainer1.jsx').default);
      });
    }}/>
    <Route path='/message/:id' getComponent={(location, cb) => {
        require.ensure([], require => {
          cb(null, require('../../components/container/DemoContainer5.jsx').default);
        });
      }}>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Then i click the following link

```
 <Link to='/message/3'>Go</Link>
```

i switch to Dev Tool, i found that it load 
http:/localhost:8080/message/10.chunk.js

so that, it cause 404. 
Anyone know how to config the Route Config to make the splitting code correctly?

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/" />` in your index.html head tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution.

webpack.config.js

```
output: {
  path: __dirname + '/client/src/assets',
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
  publicPath: '/__build__/'
},
debug: true,
devtool: 'source-map',
devServer: {
  inline:true,
  contentBase: __dirname + '/client/src/assets',
  port: 3333,
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  historyApiFallback: true,
  publicPath: '/__build__/'
},
```

Need to define the publicPath. Then webpack will base on the publicPath to load resource.

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is a bug being fixed on react router example where taion says call getComponent with nextState instead instead of location
on your Routes this should be

```
    <Router history={appHistory} >
  <Route path='/' component={RootContainer}>
    <IndexRoute component={MainContainer}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path='/demo1' getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
      require.ensure([], require => {
        cb(null, require('../../components/container/DemoContainer1.jsx').default);
      });
    }}/>
    <Route path='/message/:id' getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
        require.ensure([], require => {
          cb(null, require('../../components/container/DemoContainer5.jsx').default);
        });
      }}>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

just check the link that you [referred](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps) to in your question

where the nextState is a type RouterState

```
  type RouterState = {
location:Location,
routes: Array<Route>,
params: Params,
components:Array<Component>
}
```

Comment: here is the link to [RouterState] (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#routerstate)